Does any person in the world have the right to become a so called "U.S. National"?
Is my line of reasoning correct? In the discussion under the first answer I have already clarified some of the things that can easily be misconstrued. If all the things I have lined out are carefully and meticulously read and considered (and the devil is in the detail), then one has to come to the conclusion that literally anyone on this planet can become a U.S. national by simply pledging allegiances and conferring nationality upon themselves. I'm throwing this out here, because I want to be proven wrong!
Everything is based on US Code, Code of Federal Regulations and case law. So here we go.

Whereas “the term ‘national of the United States’ means a person who, though not a citizen of the United States, owes permanent allegiance to the United States.” - 8 U.S. Code §1101(a)(22)(B)

Whereas “a person who claims to be a national, but not a citizen, of the United States may apply to the Secretary of State for a certificate of non-citizen national status. Upon—
(2) in the case of such a person born outside of the United States or its outlying possessions, taking and subscribing, before an immigration officer within the United States or its outlying possessions, to the oath of allegiance required by this chapter of a petitioner for naturalization” - 8 U.S. Code §1452 (b) (Completely different procedure from that of the oath of renunciation and allegiance for U.S. citizenship as described in 8 U.S. Code § 1448 !). This takes reference is to persons born outside the outlying possessions of the U.S., which means it was not written for persons from American Samoa or Swains Island. Therefrom, the code addresses literally anyone other than those who are nationals at birth, which includes all natural born U.S. citizens (see: 8 U.S. Code §1401 and § 1408)!

Whereas all statutory rules, regulations, and definitions laid out in SUBCHAPTER III other than 8 U.S. Code §1401, §1408, §1452, §1481 and §1502 are pertaining to U.S. permanent residence,  naturalization of U.S. citizens, or questions concerning the subject of U.S. residence (eg. the handling of (ex-) military, Philippinos etc.), but do not contain any procedure regarding nationals whatsoever!

Whereas 8 U.S. Code §1421 names the Attorney General as the sole authority to naturalize persons as citizens of the United States. No authority is identified for the naturalization of U.S. nationals.

Whereas “the term ‘naturalization’ means the conferring of nationality of a state upon a person after birth, by any means whatsoever.” - 8 U.S. Code §1101(a)(23) (the theoretical part further down will touch on why I bolded the small "s" of the word "state")

Whereas 8 U.S. Code §1436 pertains to naturalization of non-citizens who become “resident of any State” - I presume this pertains to US citizenship. Am I wrong?

Whereas it has been “determined that those who would be eligible to apply for such a certificate (of non-citizen national status) may instead apply for a United States passport that would delineate and certify their status as a national but not a citizen of the United States.” See: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Certificates-Non-Citizen-Nationality.html

Whereas “A passport may be issued only to a U.S. national” (22 CFR 51.2). AND: “No passport shall be granted or issued to or verified for any other persons than those owing allegiance, whether citizens or not, to the United States.” - 22 U.S. Code §212.

Whereas the term “residence” refers to alien status of state membership. - Smith, Handbook of Elementary Law (1939), pp. 12-13

Whereas based on case-law I presume that the legal construct of “U.S. residence” may occur within D.C., within statutory U.S. permanent residence, or within statutory U.S. citizenship, but not solely within state-citizenship (you can have one without the other), or in mere geographical terms within a union state outside the District of Columbia or outlying possessions. (See: U.S. v. Anthony 24 Fed. 829 (1873); Murphy v. Ramsey, 114 US 15 (1885); Hendrick v. Maryland S.C. Reporter’s Rd. 610-625. (1914); Tashiro v. Jordan, 201 Cal. 236 (1927); Wheeling Steel Corp. v. Fox, 298 U.S. 193, 80. L.Ed. 1143, 56.5:Ct. 773 (1936); Crosse v. Board of Supervisors of Elections 221 A.2d 431 (1966); Jones v. Temmer, 829 F.Supp. 1226 (1993);)


Now I'm getting into unresolved interpretation:

Whereas United States is defined as “(A) a Federal corporation; (B) an agency, department, commission, board, or other entity of the United States; or (C) an instrumentality of the United States.” (28 USC § 3002(15)) Whereas United States (as corporation) is located in the District of Columbia (UCC 9-307 (h)). Whereas “The term 'United States' when used in a geographical sense includes the Commonwealth of Puerto Rico, the Virgin Islands, Guam, and American Samoa.” (26 USC § 3121(u)(2)). Whereas “The term 'United States' when used in a geographical sense includes only the States and the District of Columbia.” (26 U.S. Code §7701(9)), whereas “The term 'State' shall be construed to include the District of Columbia, where such construction is necessary to carry out provisions of this title.” (26 U.S. Code §7701(10)). Whereas “it might confuse, and is intended to designate one of the United States, the word will be capitalized 'State'." (Smith on Elementary Law p.6). Whereas “The term 'State' includes the District of Columbia, Puerto Rico, Guam, the Virgin Islands of the United States, and the Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands.” (8 U.S. Code §1101(36)). And whereas “The term 'United States', except as otherwise specifically herein provided, when used in a geographical sense, means the continental United States, Alaska, Hawaii, Puerto Rico, Guam, the Virgin Islands of the United States, and the Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands.” (8 U.S. Code §1101(38)). Whereas, there is either a contradiction, or 'the States' pursuant to §7701(9) can be nothing other than Puerto Rico, Virgin Island, Guam, American Samoa, and the District of Columbia! Whereas there is never any mention of the 50 union states other than Alaska and Hawaii. And if the term “continental United States” in §1101(38) meant anything other than the District of Columbia (which interestingly enough finds no mention in that section), then there wouldn’t be any need to mention Alaska, which after all, is a continental state, too. What makes Alaska and Hawaii distinct from all other union states, is that they were already territories (property) of the United States before having been incorporated as a “U.S. State”. All 48 lower states as such have been sovereign nations of the union, and not territories or property of the United States. They are members of the United States of America, but not property of the incorporated U.S. Each of them have their own citizenship, which was the only citizenship in the USA prior to the 14th Amendment. It would have been the citizenship of the founding fathers.

The constitution, as well as many documentations of case law, speak of "state citizenship", yet the only deviation from U.S. citizenship found in U.S. Code is the "U.S. national". Granted, it is a political status created by the United States. Yet, could it be that from U.S. perspective a state citizen and a U.S. national are one and the same thing? Or is there a distinction?
Time for your feedback! I'm looking forward to it!

Food for thought: Could it be, “illegal immigrants” from Mexico or Central America are able to stay lawfully in a union-state, because they are being conferred nationality of a state “by any means whatsoever”?

There's a lot you're quoting there, and also presumably some connections you're drawing, but it's not clear what or where they are. Overall your question is quite difficult to read. Can I suggest that you edit your question to include your full reasoning without discursions at the top, and then afterwards quote the statutes that you feel you need to quote in order to justify that reasoning?

I would also suggest that if your argument leverages trivialities like capitalization, people here are likely to mentally file it under "wild sovereign-citizen conspiracy theories", even though it probably isn't. Best to leave that stuff out. Don't blame them, blame nutters on the internet. :-(

As per law dictionary, capitalisation is not a triviality! That's why they call it "code". It is codified, so the plebs don't understand it!

Oh dear. Okay, no need to edit.

The question has been put in the header. The text body is to show the basis on which this question arose.

@Sneftel - Are you suggesting law dictionaries shall be ignored? If you don't have proper definitions (and in law that includes capitalisation -  read the source as cited please - there are a lot of other sources too! - see below), then how can you understand anything?! I care to understand, don't you?
https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/capitalization

Tobias: Since you're new here, please take the tour.  And pay particular attention to our code of conduct.

@Tobias did you read the page you linked above? It has nothing whatsoever to do with "capitalization" in the context of "using capital letters". It's about "capital" in the context of finance, tax & accounting.

US national is either a US citizen (Sec. 1401), or if not a citizen - a person born in a outlying possession of the US (or found there, or born to US nationals).
See the 8 USC 1408:

Unless otherwise provided in section 1401 of this title, the following shall be nationals, but not citizens, of the United States at birth:
(1) A person born in an outlying possession of the United States on or after the date of formal acquisition of such possession;
(2) A person born outside the United States and its outlying possessions of parents both of whom are nationals, but not citizens, of the United States, and have had a residence in the United States, or one of its outlying possessions prior to the birth of such person;
(3) A person of unknown parentage found in an outlying possession of the United States while under the age of five years, until shown, prior to his attaining the age of twenty-one years, not to have been born in such outlying possession; and
(4) A person born outside the United States and its outlying possessions of parents one of whom is an alien, and the other a national, but not a citizen, of the United States who, prior to the birth of such person, was physically present in the United States or its outlying possessions for a period or periods totaling not less than seven years in any continuous period of ten years—
(A) during which the national parent was not outside the United States or its outlying possessions for a continuous period of more than one year, and
(B) at least five years of which were after attaining the age of fourteen years.
The proviso of section 1401(g) of this title shall apply to the national parent under this paragraph in the same manner as it applies to the citizen parent under that section.

You seem to have referred to this section, but despite quoting a lot of other unrelated things you didn't put any quote from it in your question. If we're talking about conspiracy theories, then I have a couple as to why.

I don't think you read everything. For otherwise,  how do you explain 8 U.S. Code §1452 (b)(2) as quoted in my question?
"A person who claims to be a national, but not a citizen, of the United States may apply to the Secretary of State for a certificate of non-citizen national status. Upon-
(2)in the case of such a person born outside of the United States or its outlying possessions, taking and subscribing, before an immigration officer within the United States or its outlying possessions, to the oath of allegiance required by this chapter of a petitioner for naturalization,"

@Tobias what exactly is confusing you? A person who claims that they're a national need to prove their claim. But the section I quoted defines what the claim is. US nationals can be born outside the US and its territories, see the quote in my answer. One can also acquire US nationality through immigrating into the US territories and swearing the oath of allegiance. Is that what you're asking about?

If I'm already a U.S. National at birth, I don't have to naturalise as such! The United States can only naturalise you into the United States, not into a union state.

@Tobias that's a nonsensical sentence.

Naturalization is the deferring of nationality AFTER birth (8 U.S. Code §1101(a)(23)).  "Unless otherwise provided in section 1401 of this title, the following shall be nationals, but not citizens, of the United States AT birth". The devil is in the detail!

"One can also acquire US nationality through immigrating into the US territories and swearing the oath of allegiance. Is that what you're asking about?" -
What I'm asking about is if that status is attainable by "any means whatsoever", since there are absolutely no written rules pertaining to "immigrating" into that status beyond what I have already quoted. So, just move there, pledge allegiance, confer nationality upon myself, done?

*conferring, not deferring of course.

@Tobias these territories have their own immigration laws

Now we are getting to the core of it. American Samoa (one of the outlying possessions) does NOT have an immigration process of its own - see link! Unlike the 48 lower states, that have their own citizenship, territories have nothing but the US national status, which is governed solely by the U.S. - back to square one.  Do you see my point now?
https://cis.org/North/What-Can-America-Learn-Immigration-American-Samoa#:~:text=In%20American%20Samoa%20there%20is,temporary%20residents%2C%20and%20illegal%20aliens

@Tobias you cannot get naturalized in American Samoa. So? Not sure what your point is.

@Tobias: "how do you explain 8 U.S. Code §1452 (b)(2)" It can be explained by people born outside the US or its territories who were automatically non-citizen US nationals at birth, as per 8 USC 1408(2) and (4).

@Tobias: "What I'm asking about is if that status is attainable by "any means whatsoever"". No. Non-citizen US nationality cannot be attained after birth under any means.
